# How to parse Project Gutenberg rdf with php simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I am trying to parse the Project Gutenberg catalog.rdf with simplexml like this [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($etext_rdf);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}

$etext= simplexml_import_dom($dom);
print_r($etext);
```

but $etext is always empty. Any tips why? Here is the loadXML $etext_rdf that I am testing ([source of rdf here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/26783.rdf)):

```
<pgterms:etext rdf:ID="etext26783">
  <dc:publisher>&pg;</dc:publisher>
  <dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">The Story of the Kearsarge and Alabama</dc:title>
  <dc:creator rdf:parseType="Literal">Browne, A. K.</dc:creator>
  <pgterms:friendlytitle rdf:parseType="Literal">The Story of the Kearsarge and Alabama by Browne</pgterms:friendlytitle>
  <dc:language><dcterms:ISO639-2><rdf:value>en</rdf:value></dcterms:ISO639-2></dc:language>
  <dc:subject>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Kearsarge (Sloop)</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Alabama (Screw sloop)</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>United States -- History -- Civil War, 1861-1865 -- Naval operations</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
  </dc:subject>
  <dc:subject><dcterms:LCC><rdf:value>E456</rdf:value></dcterms:LCC></dc:subject>
  <dc:created><dcterms:W3CDTF><rdf:value>2008-10-06</rdf:value></dcterms:W3CDTF></dc:created>
  <pgterms:downloads><xsd:nonNegativeInteger><rdf:value>20</rdf:value></xsd:nonNegativeInteger></pgterms:downloads>
  <dc:rights rdf:resource="&lic;" />
</pgterms:etext>
```

Comment: First of all provide proof that it is empty. You might just only say so. Second, what have you tried? Did you even look at [the basic examples section in the manual](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Comment: Dude, what kind of proof you want if it is empty?

Comment: 1) Why are you importing via DOMDocument rather than using `simplexml_load_string` or `simplexml_load_file`? 2) Where is the "etext" block taken from - it doesn't seem to be either the whole or a part of the URL you linked to, and doesn't constitute an XML document on its own, because it uses namespaces. 3) Are you getting any errors or warnings? (Make sure to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: Tried simplexml_load_file and string. I am using the DOM Method because that is supposed to repair broken xml. I also have error reporting to the max.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made headway on your question, @giorgio79? Your data was there all along, but print_r is for viewing variables, not objects. This version of your code shows how to convert the object in the final print_r into a string and then use htmlentities to make the markup readable. The output is identical to the input because the only operation so far is a simple copy. Good luck taking it from here!

```
<?php
$etext_rdf = file_get_contents('http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/26783.rdf');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($etext_rdf);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}

$etext= simplexml_import_dom($dom);
// do your manipulations on the simpleXML object here..
echo '<pre>';
    print_r( htmlentities($etext->saveXML()));
echo '</pre>';
```